# Problem initializing enum using long in C++

Tags: c++, enums, long-integer

I am trying to initialize an enum using the hash codes of the type label:

```
enum ValueType {
    CLOSED = hashCode("CLOSED"),
    OPEN = hashCode("OPEN"),
    SEKIHAIRITSU = hashCode("SEKIHAIRITSU"),
    ZWEITMANDAT = hashCode("ZWEITMANDAT")
};

ValueType valuetype;
```

The `hashCode` function is an implementation of Java's function:

```
constexpr long hashCode(const char *string) {
    long h = 0;
    int off = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(string); i++) {
        h = 31 * h + string[off++];
    }

    return h;
}
```

I get an error on `Sekihairitsu` and `Zweitmandat`:

`expression must have a constant value -- value exceeds range of "long"`

The weird thing is, it isn't outside of long. When I run the `hashCode` function by myself, it returns `-1606024481` for Sekihairitsu and `-710079088` for Zweitmandat. Neither of those are outside the range of long, or even int.

Anybody know what the problem is? I have already tried `enum ValueType : long`.

Comment: You have integer overflow.  Ask yourself how are you getting negative numbers when everything you are working with is a positive number.

Comment: On my platform, `std::strlen` is not `constexpr`.  (Not sure if it is supposed to be, and my compiler isn't compliant.)

Comment: @NathanOliver I know that, but why? I ran the function by itself and it works, no integer overflow. What in the initialization of an enum would cause an Integer overflow?

Comment: Signed integer overflow is undefined behaviour, but you can always use an unsigned type like this [test here](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/4fb7rhsYK)

Comment: @MatG Thanks, I made it even easier. Just change `constexpr long` to `constexpr unsigned long`, change `h` the same way, and it works!

Comment: Shouldn't you use unsigned long?